# how to use a custom class as a JPA Id

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-roo

I have a custom class which I have to use as Id for an entity. It looks as follows

```
public class ProductId {
private final String id;

public ProductId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
        return true;
    }
    if (!(o instanceof ProductId)) {
        return false;
    }

    ProductId productId = (ProductId) o;

    if (!id.equals(productId.id)) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return id.hashCode();
}
```

}

How can I use this as Id column for a JPA entity. Would it be along the lines of

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private ProductId id;
```

I am getting inspiration and guidance from code generated by Spring ROO

Answer (score 2):

You can annotate your ID class with `@Embeddable` and annotate the field in your final entity as `@EmbeddedId`.

See: http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EmbeddedId.html

Answer (score 1):

Just define the @IdClass to be your class as per
http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_0/jpa/annotations.html#IdClass
and the PK should match these requirements
http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_0/jpa/primary_key.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are building your entities from the roo shell you can specify the id class using the `--identifierType` parameter:

```
roo> entity --class ~.YourClass --identifierType your.package.ProductId
```

Full reference: http://www.springsource.org/roo/guide?w=command-index#command-index-entity